# Perl one liner to find words longer than 63 characters

Tags: grep, regular-expression, perl, latex

I have a number of *XML* files containing sanskrit texts to be converted to *tex*. **Latex** has a maximum of 63 characters per word for its hyphenation to work, everything longer than that will not be hyphenated. Now I would like to **grep** my files for these words, only that **grep** doesn't appear to be the right tool here. Some of the words use *IAST encoding*, others *Devanāgarī*.  I suppose a **perl** one-liner could do that?

Comment: `perl -lne 'print for /\w{66,}/g'` (untested)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That's going in the right direction, but it seems for `\w` to work I would need a sanskrit locale?  Like this it doesn't catch letters with diacritics, such as ī, and it doesn't handle Devanāgarī script at all.

Comment: How about `\S{63,}` -- that will include punctuation, but should catch the long words too.

Comment: Just add `-CD` to read the input as utf8.

Comment: @choroba This seems to be almost doing it, just that it prefixes every match with a message such as `Wide character in print at -e line 1, <> line 191.`

Comment: @muk.li: Ah, so use `-CSD` to turn stdout to utf8, too.

Comment: And `XML` parser is recommended for parsing XML.

Comment: If you still need a solution, does the answer below (combined from the above comments) get close enough?

Answer (score 1):

In an attempt to give this Q a proper answer, [based](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269926/perl-one-liner-to-find-words-longer-than-63-characters#comment467978_269926) - [on](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269926/perl-one-liner-to-find-words-longer-than-63-characters#comment467988_269926) - the - [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269926/perl-one-liner-to-find-words-longer-than-63-characters#comment467992_269926) (heeding [Sobrique's note](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269926/perl-one-liner-to-find-words-longer-than-63-characters#comment499520_269926) that parsing XML should really be done with an XML parser):

```
perl -CSD -lne 'print for /\w{63,}/g' input-file-here
```

Comment: Actually I had that time already found the solution. The files being XML files didn't really matter. And `\w` (after switching input and output to utf-8) is better than `\S`, as otherwise punctuation and parts of the markup are matched, too.

Comment: I've updated it to use \w instead of \S -- I'm always a fan of what works!